# Running Jersey project (Rest web service) to tomcat

Tags: java, rest, jersey, tomcat7

I'm try to follow this guide: [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) but when I execute on the web browser it returns an error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /
type Status report
message /
description The requested resource (/rest.api/rest/hello) is not available.
```

I have installed tomcat7 in /usr/local on my mac and ran it with startup.sh on the terminal.
This is my web.xml and Hello.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>HelloRest</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>rest.api</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
package rest.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// POJO, no interface no extends

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

// This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
}

// This method is called if XML is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
}

// This method is called if HTML is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
}

}
```

This is my configuration project:

[image]

Any suggest?

Comment: What is the context root of your application? How does the request URI look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following configuration in **web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Your Service Package Name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Visit this one : [Jersey RESTful](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)

Comment: See POJOMappingFeature init param

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of Jersey the servlet-class and init-param change. Try the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>Your Service Package Name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

This worked for me using Jersey version: 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-name> jersey-serlvet </servlet-name>

<servlet-class> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer </servlet-class>

<init-param>

    <param-name> com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages </param-name>

    <param-value> rest.api </param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

    <param-name> com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature </param-name>

    <param-value> true </param-value>

</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-name> jersey-serlvet </servlet-name>

<url-pattern> /rest/* </url-pattern>
```