# Simple Rest service with Tomcat and Eclipse, Mac os. The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, rest, tomcat

I tried a lot of differents configurations following some other posts, but anything worked. I'm trying to run this simple tutorial(http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) but i'm still having the message: "The requested resource is not available". Anyone?

Running on Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7 and MAC OS 10.8.5.

I tried this configuration for the web.xml, but didn't work too (reference: [Running Jersey project (Rest web service) to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090715/running-jersey-project-rest-web-service-to-tomcat))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Hello</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and those are the jars in the last try:

1. asm-3.3.1.jar
2. jersey-bundle-1.12.jar
3. jersey-server-1.12.jar
4. jersey-servlet-1.12.jar
5. jsr311-api-1.0.jar

tried the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/Hello/
http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello
```

Comment: what is the name of your web application? i.e. the war file name (or exploded directory name).  Assume it is `Foo` then you need to call http://localhost:8080/Foo/rest/hello

Comment: the name of the project is Hello and i used the same name for the package used in the tutorial to avoid errors, and nothing yet. The name of the class is Hello too. Thanks for the help.
Using this call: http://localhost:8080/Hello/rest/hello, gave me the following error:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType [...]`
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You mapped the rest request to the path `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` so your request should be something like `http://localhost:8080/rest/Hello/`