# Why this angularJS code not working?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, rest

I have created the angularJS code that consume the RESTful service to insert some form data into MySql database. When I submit the form data, there is no response. What is the mistake in this code?

It shows the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq3En.jpg)

It shows some error messages on Eclipse console as like the following:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ang.CourseService.addC(CourseService.java:39)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/AngularDemo] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ang.CourseService.addC(CourseService.java:39)
```

This is my angularJS code:

```
var postApp = angular.module('postApp', []);
// Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
postApp.controller('postController', function($scope, $http) {
  // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.user = {};
  // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
    // Posting data to REST
    $http({
      method:'POST',
      url:'http://localhost:8080/AngularDemo/rest/courses/addNew',
      data:$scope.user,
      headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      //data:angular.toJson($scope.user),
      //headers:{'Content-Type' : 'application/json'} 
     })
      .success(function(data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorid = data.errors.id;
          $scope.errorname = data.errors.name;
          $scope.errorduration = data.errors.duration;
          $scope.errorfee = data.errors.fee;
        } else {
          $scope.message = data.message;
        }
      });
    };
});
```

This is my REST service:

```
@POST
@Path("/addNew")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addC(@FormParam("id") int i,
        @FormParam("name") String n,
        @FormParam("duration") String d,
        @FormParam("fee") Double f)throws Exception
 { 
    CourseController controller=new CourseController();
    Course c=new Course();
    c.setId(i);
    c.setName(n);
    c.setDuration(d);
    c.setFee(f);
    controller.addCourse(c); 
}
```

Comment: This is more java error, angular part is ok. Try to post with Postman, to make sure apis are ok.

Comment: When I call the same REST service from ordinary HTML it's working fine. But only the problem when I call it from angularJS.

Comment: What do you have on CourseService.java:39

Comment: In CourseService.java:39, I am having the service operation addC() as given in the above code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090715/running-jersey-project-rest-web-service-to-tomcat?rq=1 Check this, Jersey is having its problems. Are you sure you are not sending null data from post request. check if all parameters and form fields match your api params

Comment: I have not sent any null data and also I have sent all the values matched with API parameters.